# Lodash get all Objects which has a key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, lodash

I am looking for filtering object which has key

Here is my object

```
 var mydevices=    {
      "Object1": {
        "name": "name1",
        "category": "laptop"
      },
      "Object2": {
        "name": "name2",
        "category": "laptop"
      },
      "Object3": {
        "name": "name3",
        "category": "Desktop"
      },
      "Object4": {
        "name": "name4",
        "category": "Mobile"
      }
    }
```

and my filter keys are of array

```
var filterKeyArray=["Mobile","laptop"]
```

and I want to apply the filter on the category from each object.

So the filter will return me the object which has a key from filterKeyArray.

Suggest some help.

Comment: Why is `mydevices` an object and not an array? `var mydevices = [{name: "name1", category: "laptop"}, {name: "name2", category: "laptop"}, ...]; var filteredElements = mydevices.filter(d => filterKeyArray.indexOf(d.category) > -1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With lodash you can use `pickBy` to pick properties from object and pass function that uses `includes` to filter out values that are not in array. This will create new object and won't change original object.

```js
var mydevices = {"Object1":{"name":"name1","category":"laptop"},"Object2":{"name":"name2","category":"laptop"},"Object3":{"name":"name3","category":"Desktop"},"Object4":{"name":"name4","category":"Mobile"}}
var filterKeyArray=["Mobile","laptop"]

var result = _.pickBy(mydevices, e => _.includes(filterKeyArray, e.category))
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.keys()` and `Array#map` to iterate over the `mydevices` properties and check if specified element has `category` value mentioned in the `filterKeyArray` array.

**ES6** solution, no `lodash` needed.

```js
var mydevices = {Object1:{name:"name1",category:"laptop"},Object2:{name:"name2",category:"laptop"},Object3:{name:"name3",category:"Desktop"},Object4:{name:"name4",category:"Mobile"}},
    filterKeyArray = ["Mobile", "laptop"]

Object.keys(mydevices).forEach(v => filterKeyArray.some(c => c == mydevices[v].category) ? null : delete mydevices[v]);

console.log(mydevices);
```

Comment: 1. You know what [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is for? 2. Why would you destroy `mydevices`? 3. You did not read the requirement carefully

Comment: @Kinduser it is returning the object which does not has a category

Comment: @Andreas Seriously mate, you are exaggerating... about `map` fine, I should have used `forEach`, but the last two points... it's not productive at all, it's just destructive.

Comment: @Sam Oh, I'm sorry. I misunderstood your question. Now it works.

Comment: You don't know if Sam needs `mydevices` after filtering. And your solution does not what Sam asks for: "_So the filter will return me the object which has a key from filterKeyArray_". And for the deleted comment. I'm not here for the reputation/points...

Comment: @Andreas Fine, but it would be **muuuch** better if you just tell me what's wrong and how to deal with it, instead of accusing me and yelling at me 'diid you reead the quuestion??!! did you read it carefully??!!'... it makes me sad...